# Cannot assign output field name to FieldMap

Tags: arcpy, field-mapping

In attempting to map input fields to output fields, I am finding that I cannot correctly assign the output field name. Running the script produces no errors, but for a given FieldMap object, the outputField property is assigned the name of the input field. I have mapped fields many times (though never with these specific tables) and never before encountered this problem.

Here is the code:

```
field_map = arcpy.FieldMappings()  
field_map.addTable(in_select)  
fm = arcpy.FieldMap()  
fm.addInputField(in_select, "CHANGE_STA")  
REPORT_STATUS = fm.outputField  
fm.outputField = REPORT_STATUS  
REPORT_STATUS.name = "REPORT_STATUS"  
REPORT_STATUS.type = "TEXT"  
field_map.addFieldMap(fm)
```

When I then call `fm.outputField.name`, it returns the input field name `'CHANGE_STA'` (and the append I run with this field map shows that it has not mapped the fields correctly)

Any ideas? What incredibly obvious thing am I missing? (Input table is a dbf table. Is this a problem with the table type?)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the solution is straightforward, if not obvious. By swapping the code lines so that fm.outputField is defined after defining the field name attribute:

```
field_map = arcpy.FieldMappings()  
field_map.addTable(in_select)  
fm = arcpy.FieldMap()  
fm.addInputField(in_select, "CHANGE_STA")  
REPORT_STATUS = fm.outputField  
REPORT_STATUS.name = "REPORT_STATUS"  
REPORT_STATUS.type = "TEXT"
fm.outputField = REPORT_STATUS  
field_map.addFieldMap(fm)
```

The code functions as intended. *Why*, I am unsure, since I have used the code in the first iteration many times without problem.